# What are the best guides or resources for creating CSS/DIV layouts?

Tags: css, html

We have found a few online, but they all appear a bit dated.

Curious what people consider the best resources for creating and managing CSS/DIV layouts (i.e., layouts done purely in CSS with DIVs -- no tables)?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "CSS/DIV layout" exactly? Are you looking for web design resources?

Comment: That's fairly subjective, which I think is discouraged on this site.

Comment: @pekka: layouts done purely in CSS with DIVs.  no tables.  thanks for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a huge fan of http://compass-style.org/
Not only does it make creating layouts easily, but it also changes the way you think about coding css.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.apple.com/safari/

http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/

http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/more/index.html

These are the homepages for some modern browsers.  View source, there is alot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

The [Less Framework](http://lessframework.com) is a CSS/HTML framework for websites designed to display properly on a variety of displays - mobile, tablet, webpage etc.

> Less Framework is a CSS grid system
>   for designing adaptive web­sites. It
>   contains 4 layouts and 3 sets of
>   typography presets, all based on a
>   single grid

Basically use this framework as a basis for a new, clean site and then add in your styles.

Answer (score 0):

I always considered http://www.csszengarden.com/ to be a good example for div and css design.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you mean — there are lots of books that teach CSS the language, but not a lot that purely discuss using it to lay out web pages, starting from the layouts you might want to achieve.

I think that’s partially due to IE’s dodgy float support up until 8 and 9. Any discussion of layouts rapidly descends into murky, complex discussions of IE’s various bugs.

Hopefully the situation will improve as older versions of IE die out. Until then, although I’ve not read it myself, I think [‘Bulletproof Web Design’ by Dan Cederholm](http://simplebits.com/publications/bulletproof/) has a couple of good chapters focused on layout.